# Not able to detect interrupt on GPIO 2

Tags: python, rpi.gpio

I have counter which is sending pulse every second to GPIO 2 and I wrote the following code to detect it

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(2, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
def my_callback(channel):
    print "edge detected on 3"
GPIO.add_event_detect(2, GPIO.BOTH, callback=my_callback)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

and I run the code using sudo python test.py but this code doesn't do anything, it just exits. I have checked using multimeter so pulse in being send to pin 3.

Comment: Note that there are 3 different ways of numbering the GPIO pins. Broadcom GPIO pin 2 isn't connected to GPIO header of the Pi. Try using `GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)` and changing `2` to some other number, as pin 2 is the 5volt line.

Answer (score 1):

GPIO 2 (board 3) is intended for I2C connections and has a [pull-up resistor permanently connected](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/7007/11223) - the `pull_up_down` option will therefore have no effect. I don't believe it's possible to pull this (or board pin 5) to ground while the pin is configured as an input.

I can only suggest you try using a different pin to detect the external signal.

Answer (score 0):

Pin P1-3 is connected to gpio#2 on Rev.2 boards and gpio#0 on Rev.1 boards.

It has a 1K8 pull-up to 3V3 so your pulse will need to be pulling the signal low for it to have any effect.

You could use gpio#4 (pin P1-7) and have a pull-down rather than a pull-up if you are sending a high pulse.